# How to read data into different groups as specified

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I use the below code, to read data from into two groups

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats
dataFileName='RFInput.xlsx'
sheetName='Rawdata'
sheetNamePara='paraList'
dataRaw=pd.read_excel(dataFileName, sheetname = sheetName)
datapara=pd.read_excel(dataFileName, sheetname = sheetNamePara)

noData=len(dataRaw)
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.cross_validation import cross_val_score
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler


labels = datapara
x = dataRaw[labels]
y = dataRaw['classVariable']
```

Rawdata:

```
A   B     C      D    E      F
0   1.2   1.6   3.2  3.2    1.6
1   1.2   1.6   3.2  3.2    1.6
2   2.6   1.9   6.5  6.5    1.9
0   1.2   1.6   3.2  3.2    1.6
1   2.6   1.9   6.5  6.5    1.9
4   1.2   1.6   3.2  3.2    1.6


paraList:
A   C  E  F
Y   N  Y  Y
```

A, B, C, D, E, F are my original variable names in rawData, but I want to only extract A, C, E, F variables data specified in paraList. These required varibles are listed in  paraList, and they separated into two groups Y & N,
I want to read Y variables data into x_Y, and N variables data into x_N.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want a subset of your original table. You don't need to read the file twice, it is completely sufficient to just index your dataframe like `dataRaw[["A","C","E","F"]]`. You can either point this view into another variable or copy it with an added `.copy()`.

But since this is a rather basic question I would really recommend reading the [10 minutes pandas introduction](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html).

**Edit**
In this case I would suggest storing the column and category list into a dictionary and use a simple list comprehension to access them, something like this

```
dic = {"A":"Y","C":"N","E":"Y","F":"Y"}
y_subset = df[[key for key,value in dic.items() if value == "Y"]]
n_subset = df[[key for key,value in dic.items() if value == "N"]]
```

Comment: Because, my rawData has more variables, but I every time define which variables data I need in "datapara", the list of variables in datapara changes every time as it required, and the list of  variables in datapara  are two categories such as N, Y, I want to identify which variables are Y type, and which variables are N type, after identifying the N & Y category varialbes, then read the N type variables data & Y types varialbles data from dataRaw separatly.